# A value in a foreach loop does not increment / use of local variables

Tags: c#, excel, loops, increment

My code should import some values from an Excel file to a dictionary and then print them out as an xml file. This is a part of my code that is relevant to the problem:

```
static Dictionary<string, SL_Weapon> dict_Swords_1h = new Dictionary<string, SL_Weapon>();
```

```
public static void LoadExcelDataForXML()
{           
            WorkSheet ws = wb.GetWorkSheet("Swords_1h");
            int i = 1;
            
            SL_Weapon generic = new SL_Weapon()
            {
                Name = ws.Rows[i].Columns[1].ToString(),
                Target_ItemID = ws.Rows[i].Columns[0].IntValue,
                //+ a bunch of other columns
                ...
            }

            void LoadExcel_Swords_1h()
            {
                ws = wb.GetWorkSheet("Swords_1h");
                i = 1;
                foreach (var item in ws["B2:B40"])
                {
                    dict_Swords_1h.Add(ws.Rows[i].Columns[1].ToString(), generic);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            LoadExcel_Swords_1h();
}
```

```
static public void WriteToXML()
        {
            string itemClass = "SL_MeleeWeapon";
            string statsHolderClass = "\"SL_WeaponStats\"";
            Dictionary<string, SL_Weapon>.ValueCollection swords_1h = dict_Swords_1h.Values;
            foreach (SL_Weapon weapon in swords_1h)
            {
                string path = @"C:\Users\Marcin\Desktop\Outward - Mody Moje\Outward Enhanced - Weapons - Import From Excel\dupa\"+weapon.Name+".xml";
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("  <Name>" + weapon.Name + "</Name>");
                    //and a bunch of other stats
                    ...
                 }
            }
}
```

Now, the problem is that the line `ws.Rows[i].Columns[1].ToString()` (which is basically a name of a weapon) that is located in the `void LoadExcel_Swords_1h()` method  works just fine (meaning `i` increments as I want it to, so I get 39 different items from the Excel file), but the same line that is located in the initializer of `SL_Weapon generic = new SL_Weapon()` does not increment. So I have 39 different items in my `dict_Swords_1h` dictionary, each one has (obviously) a unique `Key` that is the name of the weapon from each consecutive row in the Excel file. However all items have identical names (and other stats) which are taken from row 1 in the Excel file, meaning `i` does not increment in the `Values` part of my Dictionary and always stays at 1.
Why is this happening? I would like `i` to increment in both cases so that each weapon has its unique stats loaded from its corresponding row in the Excel file.

I think it's worth mentioning that if I put `SL_Weapon generic = new SL_Weapon()` initializer inside the `void LoadExcel_Swords_1h()` method not before it, everything works fine. The thing is that I've got more similar methods and I wanted to find a way to avoid repetition. Otherwise I have to repeat the whole initializer code inside each one of those methods.

Comment: You need to initialize your generic item in the loop so that it gets the fields from the proper rows.  Right now, generic is the same every time. it will never change because you aren't changing it. You need to create a new `SL_Weapon` for each dictionary entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new SL_Weapon for each weapon you are adding to the dictionary. Your nested method `LoadExcel_Swords_1h` is unnecessary.  Your code can be simplified to use a for loop like this.

```
public static void LoadExcelDataForXML()
{           
    //Grab the worksheet           
    WorkSheet ws = wb.GetWorkSheet("Swords_1h");
    //Loop over rows 2 to 40
    for (var i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
    {
        //Create a new instance of weapon from the row
        var weapon = new SL_Weapon()
        {
            Name = ws.Rows[i].Columns[1].ToString(),
            Target_ItemID = ws.Rows[i].Columns[0].IntValue,
            //+ a bunch of other columns
            ...
        }
        //Add the weapon to the dictionary
        dict_Swords_1h.Add(weapon.Name, weapon);
    }
}
```

To Address your concern about repetition, you can modify SL_Weapon to accept a constructor argument of type row and pass that into it.  When doing so it would look like this

```
public class SL_Weapon()
{
    public SL_Weapon(Row row)
    {
        Name = row.Columns[1].ToString(),
        Target_ItemID = row.Columns[0].IntValue,
        ...
    }
}
```

Your loop would then look something like this

```
public static void LoadExcelDataForXML()
{           
    //Grab the worksheet           
    WorkSheet ws = wb.GetWorkSheet("Swords_1h");
    //Loop over rows 2 to 40
    for (var i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
    {
        //Create a new instance of weapon from the row
        var weapon = new SL_Weapon(ws.Rows[i]);
        //Add the weapon to the dictionary
        dict_Swords_1h.Add(weapon.Name, weapon);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution should help (I still need to try it). But I don't understand why what I did, didn't work. I have the statement ```dict_Swords_1h.Add(ws.Rows[i].Columns[1].ToString(), generic)``` in a loop, and ```generic = new SL_Weapon ...etc```. Well it EQUALS to a new SL_Weapon, right? so as I understand it, for each iteration of the loop a new object of SL_Weapon class should be created. I mean, I could write the initializer in each method, repeating the code and it would work. Here, I just assigned the whole initializer to the ```generic``` variable and used it instead.

Comment: You only created a new SL_Weapon once.  That was not inside your loop so it is the same every time.  It always has the same values.  You were essentially adding the same object to every value in your dictionary.  You need to create a new object inside the loop to make one for each weapon.

Comment: OH, wait. Actually the solution you proposed does not solve my problem. I actually had it done almost exactly the same way before BUT the thing is, I have more worksheets like Swords_1h, Swords_2h, etc. And the whole point was to avoid repeating the ```new SL_Weapon``` initializer in each case.

Comment: You can't avoid the new initializer.  You have to create a new instance for every dictionary entry.  This is how OOP works.  You can't use the same object to store multiple version of itself.

Comment: I also proposed a solution to ease the initialization by using a constructor that takes the row as a parameter. Then your initialization code is only written once.

Comment: OK, that's a shame then. I simply thought that if I assign the initializer to the ```generic``` value, every time I call ```generic``` it should create a new object of the SL_Weapon class, not point the the particular that has already ben created. Though, this does make sense as well, I think.
I'll try the constructor approach.

Comment: Alright, the solution with the constructor does what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as accepted if this has solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you are trying to do, you are only calling the constructor for `SL_Weapon`  once so you are always going to get the same names.  So you need to just create a constructor `SL_Weapon(int i)` that takes an integer parameter then call `generic = new SL_Weapon(i);` each time through the for loop.